# Connect to Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, api, rest, sharepoint

Using the clientid, client_secret and Tenant ID I'm able to connect using Postman service. But I'm trying to write a Python script and connect to Sharepoint using the below code. But I'm getting an invalid request error.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

# Set your credentials and endpoint
client_id = "your_client_id"
client_secret = "your_client_secret"
tenant_id = "your_tenant_id"
site_url = "https://mtu.sharepoint.com/teams/folderName"
list_title = "Your List Title"

# Authenticate
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}")
try:
    if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id, client_secret):
        ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
        # Load the list data
        list_data = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).get_items().execute_query()
        # Print the data
        for item in list_data:
            print(item.properties)
    else:
        print("Failed to acquire access token.")
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Authentication error: {ex}")
```

**Error**
It fails at this step: `ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app`. "Specified tenant identifier 'none' is neither a valid DNS name nor a valid external domain"